# Problema ao criar projeto com Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Um bom dia pessoal,

Estou começando meus estudos em Angular 2, utilizo docker para gerenciamento de meus contêineres.

Logo no começo já estou tendo problemas, a criação do projeto vem apresentando erros.

Ao executar o comando:

```
ng new primeiro-projeto
```

Ocorre o seguinte problema...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fiquei nessa tela por um longo tempo e nada, aparentemente a criação do projeto simplesmente travou...

Versões utilizadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem saberia me dizer o por que desse erro ?

Comment: De vez em quando o `powershel` trava mesmo, eu costumo da um `control+c` ou alguns enter dentro dele!

Comment: Esta mensagem parece normal e nao de erro.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o git bash (que vem quando você instala o Git para Windows).
O npm tem problemas no Windows principalmente com esta load bar quando está instalando pacotes.

Você pode testar também utilizando a flag para remover a load/progress bar :

```
npm install --no-progress
```

Espero ter ajudado.